# Redirect \tag\ to homepage

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, tags

I want to redirect my all

```
www.website.com/tag/xxxx.html
```

links to

```
www.website.com
```

How can i do that with .htaccess file?

I've tried

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (tag)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ www.website.com [R=301,L]
```

but not worked

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can use `mod_rewrite` based rule:**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^tag(/.*)?$ http://www.website.com/ [R=301,L,NC]
```

**PS:** You will need first 2 `RewriteCond` lines only when you want to avoid this rule for valid files/directories.

**OR using `mod_alias`:**

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/tag(/.*)?$ http://www.website.com/
```

**UPDATE:** As per your comments:

```
RewriteRule ^def/any/(.+)$ /$1 [R=301,L,NC]
```

Comment: Thank you i placed first one it works. Does it redirect also www.website.com/tagabcdh.html?

Comment: No that won't be redirected. Do you want `tagabcdh.html` to redirect also?

Comment: If this answer helped you solve your problem, please consider marking it as "accepted", so users facing a similar problem in the future will be able to see it easily.

Comment: Ok how can i redirect www.abc.com/def/any/way/1-g.html to www.abc.com/way/1-g.html?

Comment: Check **UPDATE** rule.

Comment: There are lots of links containing def but i want to direct only def/any containing links